# Trying to manipulate objects in an array using an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, file, loops

I'm reading in two different text files, one with data about the `Salesperson`, the other containing the `SalesStats` for each person. However, when I try to set the `SalesStats` to each person, I'm getting an index out of bounds error and I'm not sure why. I've noted with comments where this error pops up.

**Question: How can I fix the index out of bounds error and have each `Salesperson` be given their proper `SalesStats`?**

TEXT FILES:

```
PEOPLE:
        1,Skippy,Jones
        2,Rod,Stewart
        3,Betty,Velveta
        4,Gina,Ginger
        5,Paul,Funyun

STATS:
    1   120
    1   130
    1   140
    1   150
    1   160
    1   170
    1   180
    1   190
    1   200
    1   210
    1   220
    1   230
    2   240
    2   250
    2   260
    ETC....
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
        at java.util.ArrayList.set(ArrayList.java:444)
        at SalespersonDriver.main(SalespersonDriver.java:72)
```

CODE:

```
public class SalespersonDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

double monthSales = 0;
                int currentLine = 0;
                int currentLine2 = 0;
                int personNumber = 0;
                int personNumber2 = 0;
                String firstName = "";
                String lastName = "";
                Salesperson[] SalesPeople = new Salesperson[5];
                ArrayList<Double> SalesStats1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
                ArrayList<Double> SalesStats2= new ArrayList<Double>();
                ArrayList<Double> SalesStats3 = new ArrayList<Double>();
                ArrayList<Double> SalesStats4 = new ArrayList<Double>();
                ArrayList<Double> SalesStats5 = new ArrayList<Double>();



                // reads in NewPeople.txt
                        File NewPeople = new File("./src/NewPeople.txt");
                        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(NewPeople);

                        // while there is a new line in the data, goes to the next one
                        while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                            String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                            Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
                            lineScanner.useDelimiter("\\,");

                            // while there is a new attribute to read in on a given line, reads data
                            while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
                                personNumber = lineScanner.nextInt();
                                firstName = lineScanner.next();
                                lastName = lineScanner.next();

                                SalesPeople[currentLine] = new Salesperson(personNumber, firstName, lastName);
                                currentLine++;
                            }

                    // reads in SalesFigures.txt
                            File SalesFigures = new File("./src/SalesFigures.txt");
                            Scanner fileScanner2 = new Scanner(SalesFigures);

                            // while there is a new line in the data, goes to the next one
                            while (fileScanner2.hasNextLine()) {
                                String line2 = fileScanner2.nextLine();
                                Scanner lineScanner2 = new Scanner(line2);
                                lineScanner2.useDelimiter(" ");

                                // while there is a new attribute to read in on a given line, reads data
                                while (lineScanner2.hasNext()) {

                                    personNumber2 = lineScanner2.nextInt();     
                                    monthSales = lineScanner2.nextDouble();     

                                    if(personNumber2 == 1)
                                    {
                                        SalesStats1.set(currentLine2, monthSales); //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                    }
                                    else if(personNumber2 == 2)
                                    {
                                        SalesStats2.set(currentLine2, monthSales);
                                    }
                                    else if(personNumber2 == 3)
                                    {
                                        SalesStats3.set(currentLine2, monthSales);
                                    }
                                    else if(personNumber2 == 4)
                                    {
                                        SalesStats4.set(currentLine2, monthSales);
                                    }
                                    else if(personNumber2 == 5)
                                    {
                                        SalesStats5.set(currentLine2, monthSales);
                                    }

                                    currentLine2++;
                                }

                                SalesPeople[0].setSalesStats(SalesStats1);
                                SalesPeople[1].setSalesStats(SalesStats2);
                                SalesPeople[2].setSalesStats(SalesStats3);
                                SalesPeople[3].setSalesStats(SalesStats4);
                                SalesPeople[4].setSalesStats(SalesStats5);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full stack trace.

Comment: Please indicate line# **72** of your `SalespersonDriver.java` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fail when calling `set` method of `ArrayList`.

You instantiate `SalesStats1-5` then call `set` on them without ever adding any data.

The list is empty and you call the `set` method which is illogical as the `set` is meant to be used to override data at a specified index but the list is actually empty. Use [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) method instead which will add to the next index and will also allow you to get rid of the useless `currentLine2` insignifiant memory holder.

The doc specify that `set`

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the
>   specified element.

and will throws

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 ||
>   index >= size())

In your case, the index given is 0 and the size is 0 which enter the clause `index >= size()`, hence throw the exception.

Comment: So can I just do SalesStats1.add(monthSales); and it will update each successive index as it loops through?

Comment: @Jordan Yes, it will always add to the next index, try it.

Comment: I'm getting a null pointer exception at all the objects in SalesPeople in the array except for SalesPeople[0].  Do you think there's something wrong with how I created the Salesperson objects?

Comment: Print where you add SalesPerson to the array to see if it add more then one person.

Answer (score 0):

the ArrayList.set(int index,
       E element) method will throw that exception if

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index >= size())
```

you should probably use ArrayList.add(int index,
       E element) method because that will throw exception if

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())
```

one is greater than and one is greater than or equal to

you cant set(0,element) if there is no 0 already